# ASP.Net MVC Validation (server side)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

asp.net mvc server side validation when the javascript is disabled in the browser? i used "remote" in my modal class it validates only when the javascript is enabled it doesnt validate when the javascript is disabled.

Scenario for my problem is i have a table in my db with a column "code" with the datatype varchar. any one inserts the data they must insert the unique code. 
Please do help me out

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to forget about `remote` because if you are using code first entity framework, you can't have more that one `unique` column in your table. I would just write code for it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Insert a new user into the database
        using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
        {
            UserProfile email = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email.ToLower() == model.Email.ToLower());
            try
            {
                // Check if email already exists
                if (email == null)
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email });
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email address already exists. Please enter a different email address.");
                }
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace the email with the property you want to validate. At post, this will compare with entries with what already exists in your database, and depending on results, it will give you feedback. Throws exception if such data exists.